# Surface Equation

Tags: python, surface

I want a set of 3D points and I want to find the equation that they describe. Something like `z = f(x, y)`.
The surface fitting method I am using is this one:

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,2,0.5), np.arange(0,2,0.5))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()

 # best-fit quadratic curve
A = np.c_[np.ones(capo_mesh.shape[0]), capo_mesh[:,:2], np.prod(capo_mesh[:,:2], axis=1), capo_mesh[:,:2]**2]
C,_,_,_ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, capo_mesh[:,2])

# evaluate it on a grid
Z = np.dot(np.c_[np.ones(XX.shape), XX, YY, XX*YY, XX**2, YY**2], C).reshape(X.shape)


# plot points and fitted surface
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.2)
ax.scatter(capo_mesh[:,0], capo_mesh[:,1], capo_mesh[:,2], c='r', marker=".")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.axis('auto')
ax.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

which I took from this thread: https://gist.github.com/raacampbell/1c8db957d4f4620c60c3b41e8831d536

As long as I understand, the scipy.linalg.lstsq function stores in `C` the values of the coefficients. If I do `print(C)` it gives me the following:

```
[-4.79585721e-02  1.48075202e-01  4.61947721e-01  1.22189838e-04
 -8.75774625e-02 -1.55696550e-01]
```

How do I transform those points to an equation `z = f(x, y)`?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find the function `f`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 EXACTLY. I want to find a function z = f(x,y) that describes a surface that best fits those points

Comment: @mkrieger1 The one I found is the one I pasted there, but now I am unable to stablish a connection between the numbers I mention and the coefficients of my polynomial function.

Comment: Well you already found it. It's a quadratic function with the coefficients `C` (according to the comment `best-fit quadratic curve`. You need to figure out what the coefficients mean given the function you put into `scipy.linalg.lstsq`.

Comment: Yes, that is why I am asking here. In fact if you see the plot that that generates it is a surface which is very close to the points. But I am stuck in figuring out which number is which coefficient

Comment: @mkrieger1 I mean, from this list that Python generates with the solutions: [-4.79585721e-02  1.48075202e-01  4.61947721e-01  1.22189838e-04
 -8.75774625e-02 -1.55696550e-01] . Which number is which coefficient or how I am supposed to guess it?

Comment: My guess is that the function is `C[0] + C[1] * X + C[2]* Y + C[3] * X * Y + C[4] * X * X + C[5] * Y * Y` given the line under `evaluate it on a grid`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I also thought that, but I tried to plot the function in geogebra and it isn't the same, anyway let me check again